# Auto Trigger a Mysql query every day at specific time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, database-trigger

I want to give my users bonus every day at 00:01 AM, so i am looking for an automatic trigger in mysql to update Bonus in users.

```
UPDATE users SET bonus = bonus + 10
```

How can i do this ?

Thank you

Comment: A CRON job is all you need to accomplish your task

Comment: you can write a .sql file, add this query in it and run it timely as a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a [built-in scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html) that can be used to execute tasks according to a given schedule.

Here is how to [create a scheduled event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) for your use case:

```
create event grant_user_bonus_daily
on schedule every 1 day
starts current_date + interval 1 day + interval 1 minute -- starts tomorrow at 00:01
do
    update users set bonus = bonus + 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Example:

```
CREATE EVENT test_event_02
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
   INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at)
   VALUES('Test MySQL Event 2',NOW());
```

Full tutorial [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

Official MySQL [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)